# Calling an async WCF method throws an exception

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, service

I have a WCF service, that needs to convert a video. I need to call that method from my Xamarin app. If I call the regular method everything works as expected, but if I call the Async method, I get the error below.
I already set the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults on my WCF service to true, to get the details of the error.

**WCF:**

The interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IConvert
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool ConvertVideo(string path);
}
```

The service:

```
public class ConvertService : IConvert
{
    public bool ConvertVideo(string path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Converting video... wait 3 sec");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Video converted!");
        Console.WriteLine(path);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Xamarin:**

This works:

```
try
{
    _Client.ConvertVideo(GetFullFtpPath());
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

This throws an error:

```
try
{
    _Client.ConvertVideoAsync(GetFullFtpPath());
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

The error:

```
{System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: 
Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ConvertVideo'. 
OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. 
Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'ConvertVideo' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. 
Found node type 'Element' with name 'ConvertVideoAsync' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' 
(Fault Detail is equal to Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ConvertVideo'. 
OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. 
Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'ConvertVideo' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. 
Found node type 'Element' with name 'ConvertVideoAsync' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/').}
```

*EDIT:* This only happens on Xamarin. I have tried it with WPF and everything works fine there.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am getting same error here. For Xamarin Android it only generates Async methods. This is weird because I am only getting this error on Xamarin Forms netstandard version, not previous PCL version.

Comment: @hushyon No, it seems that this approach doesn't work on Xamarin. I implemented a workaround where I poll the server every couple of seconds.
More elegant approach is to implement SignalR for the communication with the server, without the need of polling.

Answer (score 0):

your _Client should have `_Client.ConvertVideoCompleted`. your code should be something like

```
try
{
 _Client.ConvertVideoCompleted+= yourHandler;
  _Client.ConvertVideo(GetFullFtpPath());
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-call-wcf-service-operations-asynchronously

Comment: That won't get rid of the error. Your solution only gives me a way to know when the task is completed, but the error is still there.

Comment: I see now that it works in WPF. in which case, Are you using the same proxy classes in the Xamrin client and WPF client?

Comment: Yes, I use the same proxy classes in both cases. It is weird because I can call the regular method from Xamarin, but I get an error when I try to call the Async method.